# Failed to create nodeport error, after deploying ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, voyager

Failed to create NodePort error, after deploying ingress

I have an ingress defined as in the screenshot:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CPMU.png)

The 2 replicas of an Ingress server are not spinning due to the Failed to create NodePort error. Please advice

Comment: We need more details here. How did you deployed your Ingress Operator? What is your K8s version and where do you run it? Have you checked any relevant logs besides the events from the screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the error says. You are missing the `NodePortPods` [CRD](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/). It looks like that CRD existed at some point in time. But I don't see it anymore in the [repo](https://github.com/voyagermesh/voyager/blob/master/pkg/ingress/nodeport.go). You didn't specify how you deployed the ingress operator but you can make sure you install the latest.

```sh
helm repo add appscode https://charts.appscode.com/stable/
helm repo update
helm search repo appscode/voyager --version v13.0.0
# Generate the template to check or use helm install
helm template voyager-operator appscode/voyager --version v13.0.0 --namespace kube-system  --no-hooks --set cloudProvider=baremetal  Use the right cloud provider
```

✌️

Comment: Thank you for responding, i tried with this version. still 2 replicas of an Ingress server are not spinning. im using version appscode/voyager:v12.0.0-rc.2

Comment: What do you mean they are not spinning? are they crashing?